# Calculator for fractions using classes

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to create a four functions (+,-,/,*) calculator for fractions using classes .There is something wrong with the getinf function, whenever i call it it always returns the same value in the main function. I cant figure out the what is causing this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cmath>
#include<process.h>

using namespace std;
class frac{
    long num,dum;
    public:
    void getinf(){                              
        cout<<"Enter the fraction = ";
        cin>>num>>dum;
        if(cin.fail()) {
            cout<<"Invalid data entered. "<<"\nTry again. ";getch();exit(0);
        }
    }
    frac add(frac f1,frac f2){
        frac f3;
        f3.num=((f1.num*f2.dum)+(f1.dum*f2.dum));
        f3.dum=f1.dum*f2.dum;
        return f3;
    }
    frac sub(frac f1,frac f2){
        frac f3;
        f3.num=((f2.num*f2.dum)-(f1.dum*f2.dum));
        f3.dum=f1.dum*f2.dum;
        return f3;
    }
    frac mul(frac f1,frac f2){          
        frac f3;
        f3.num=f1.num*f2.num;
        f3.dum=f1.dum*f2.dum;
        return f3;
    }
    frac div(frac f1,frac f2){
        frac f3;
        f3.num=f1.num*f2.dum;
        f3.dum=f1.dum*f2.num;
        return f3;
    }

    void lowterm(){
        long tnum,tdum,temp,gcd;
        tnum=labs(num);
        tdum=labs(dum);
        if(tdum==0) {
            cout<<"Illegal fraction division by 0";exit(1);
        } else if(tnum==0) {
            num=0;dum=1;return;
        }
        while(tnum!=0){
            if(tnum<tdum) {
                temp=tnum;tnum=tdum;tdum=temp;
            }
            tnum=tnum-tdum;
        }
        gcd=tdum;
        num=num/gcd;
        dum=dum/gcd;
    }

    void showinf(){
        cout <<"The result is "<<num<<"/"<<dum;getch();
    }
};


void main(){
    frac s1,s2,s3;char ch = 'a' ;
    s1.getinf();
    s2.getinf();
    cout<<"Enter the function you want to perform on the fractions (+,-,*,/): ";
    cin>>ch;
    if(cin.fail()){
        cout<<"Invalid operation entered. "<<"\nNo such operation exist. " <<"\nTry again. ";
        getch();
        exit(0);
    }
    switch(ch){
        case'+':s3.add(s1,s2);break;
        case'-':s3.sub(s1,s2);break;
        case'*':s3.mul(s1,s2);break;
        case'/':s3.div(s1,s2);break;
        default:cout<<"Wrong information entered. "<<"\nTry again. ";
    }
    s3.lowterm();
    s3.showinf();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Mat can you explain a little bit more. I am trying to get numerator and denominator for from the user for fraction s1. Is there anything wrong in syntax ?

Comment: Sorry, misread one of your functions. getinf is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your "operator" functions, e.g.:

```
frac mul(frac f1,frac f2){
    frac f3;
    f3.num=f1.num*f2.dum;
    f3.dum=f1.dum*f2.num;
    return f3;
}
```

This function:

- Creates a brand new `frac` object called `f3`
- Sets that object's `num` and `dum` members
- Returns the object.

In particular, at no point does it set `this`'s `num` or `dum` members.

When you call `s3.mul(...)` in main, you completely ignore `mul`'s return value. Since `mul` doesn't do anything else than operate on the object it's returning, that call is essentially a no-op.

You should change your operator functions so that they actually change the object's fields like this:

```
void mul(frac f1,frac f2){
    num=f1.num*f2.dum;
    dum=f1.dum*f2.num;
}
```

Or make them free functions (or static members) and call them with something like:

```
frac result = mul(s1, s2); // or frac::mul(s1, s2) for a static member
```

(Also note that your `div` function has the same code as your `mul` function, which is probably a bug.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you should change your switch block as:

```
switch(ch){
    case'+':s3=s3.add(s1,s2);break;
    case'-':s3=s3.sub(s1,s2);break;
    case'*':s3=s3.mul(s1,s2);break;
    case'/':s3=s3.div(s1,s2);break;
    default:cout<<"Wrong information entered. "<<"\nTry again. ";
```

and your code will be fine.